# How should i specify the analysis of a field to not_analyzed when creating index using Transport Client

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-6.1.1.As the CreateIndexRequest api is not provided by JavaHighLeve client-6.1.1 i tried to create the index by working around with TransportClient as given here:(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/_changing_the_application_8217_s_code.html)
The code is:

```
public class IndexOperations {

    RestHighLevelClient client ;
    public IndexOperations(RestHighLevelClient client){
        this.client = client ; 
    }

    public void indexOperations()throws UnknownHostException,IOException  {

        TransportClient transportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"),9300));


        String mapping = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                        .startObject()
                            .startObject("delllogfiles")
                                .startObject("properties")

                                    .startObject("message")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("logid")
                                        .field("type","long")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("version")
                                        .field("type","long")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("qualifiers")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("level")
                                        .field("type","long")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("task")
                                        .field("type","long")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("opcode")
                                        .field("type","long")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("keywords")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("recordid")
                                        .field("type","long")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("providername")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("providerid")
                                        .field("type","long")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("logname")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("processid")
                                        .field("type","long")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("threadid")
                                        .field("type","long")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("machinename")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("userid")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("timecreated")
                                        .field("type","date")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("activityid")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("relatedactivityid")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("containerlog")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("matchedqueryids")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("bookmark")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("levldispalyname")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("opcodedisplayname")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("taskdisplayname")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("keywordsdisplayname")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                    .startObject("properties")
                                        .field("type","text")
                                        .field("index","not_analyzed")
                                    .endObject()

                                .endObject()
                            .endObject()
                        .endObject()
                        .string(); 


        CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = transportClient.admin().indices()
                                                    .prepareCreate("logfiles")
                                                    .addMapping("delllogfiles",mapping,XContentType.JSON)
                                                    .get();

        System.out.println("finally index created "+createIndexResponse.isAcknowledged());
        transportClient.close();
```

when is run the code i get an exception as :

```
Exception in thread "main" MapperParsingException[Failed to parse mapping [delllogfiless]: Could not convert [message.index] to boolean]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Could not convert [message.index] to boolean]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Failed to parse value [not_analyzed] as only [true] or [false] are allowed.];
```

How can i set anaylzer of a field to not_analyzed when using TransportClient ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From elastic search 5 index property has only two options

- true
- false

For not_analyzed string fields use field type **keyword** instead of **text** which is by default not_analyzed

Here is the link to it.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html